# Resharper challenge: Using .Mock().Return() instead of setters and vice versa

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, rhino-mocks

I often have a problem related to the way Rhino Mocks forces you to use setters when they are available, instead of mocking (and vice versa).

For example:

```
var foo = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IFoo>();

// Valid only if Bar has a setter (of course, otherwise it wouldn't compile)
foo.Bar = new Bar(); 

// Valid only if Bar does not have a setter (less obvious, as this will compile)
foo.Stub(x => x.Bar).Return(new Bar());
```

Dealing with these can be a real hassle, especially when doing refactoring.

So my question is, can anyone think of a good way to customize a Resharper/Visual Studio shortcut that would allow me to quickly convert from one to the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question - a custom inspection pattern can help with this.

The search pattern is:
$object$.$property$ = $value$;

The replace pattern is:
$object$.Stub(x => x.$property$).Return($value$);

$object$ and $value$ are both expression placeholders, and $property$ is an identifier placeholder.

Unfortunately, because this as a Code Inspection it is visible all the time, causing green squiggles to appear throughout the code base.

Comment: Yes, but then you can't execute it using a shortcut.

Comment: Ah of course. Can you set it to Hint (so all you get is the faintest of dashed underlines)?

Comment: Yeah that's what I've done - it's easy to set it as "Hint" when I want to use it, then set it back to "Do not show" when I don't need it anymore.